# Bookmarklet to refresh page every minute or so, so I don't lose session data whilst on lunch

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've just entered a load of data into a site that I'm testing. I don't want to enter it again, but want to go for lunch, and the session will have expired by the time I get back.

A bookmarklet would be handy (as this situation occurs often) to keep refreshing the page, every minute or so.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This bookmarklet reloads the page every 5min, almost certainly keeping the session active as if you had just opened a new tab; the trick is to reload the page in a **separate window/tab** as follows.

```
javascript:_x=setInterval(function(){open(location.href, 'otherWindow')}, 1000*60*5)
```

You will have to disable your popup blocker / allow the first window to open. Obviously only one new window is created, else this would be a terrible solution.

To test this, merely replace 1000*60*5 with something like 1000*5 (5 seconds).

---

The user didn't really need it for his use case, but if someone else wants to avoid closing the page, you can just use this bookmarklet to stop the refreshing.

```
javascript:clearInterval(_x)
```

Comment: That won't work, because the page refreshes and loses the interval =) Little bit too simple

Comment: Your comment is completely incorrect, note that it opens in a **new window**. That is the entire idea behind this answer, as stated.

Comment: And when you close the original window (you will), the interval stops... Right?

Comment: If the user chooses to close the window when they get back from lunch (not sure why you are so insistent "**you will**"), then yes, the other page will stop refreshing. If you have any further questions you are welcome to use the script yourself; this question could have easily been answered by copy-pasting.