# Page Monitor Bookmarklet That Clears Cookies or Cache After Each Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, web, bookmarklet

Okay I changed the plan. How would I create a bookmarklet that refreshes a link and clears cache until a page change is detected?

Edit: this might help (from [JavaScript Bookmarklet; click button, reload page, then open page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703056/javascript-bookmarklet-click-button-reload-page-then-open-page)):
If a page reloads, any code currently running on that page, including code from a bookmarklet, is ended and removed. Traditionally bookmarklet code ceases to work after a page load and user clicks it again.

There are three workarounds that I know of.

A.) Change the process that loads the page to instead use AJAX.

B.) Change the process that loads the page to instead open a new window, and then use JavaScript to manipulate the new window.

C.) Before triggering the page load, open a new child window and insert code into it. The code in that child window can then monitor its parent and take actions on the parent even after the parent has reloaded.

Edit 2: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5977228/7615373) refreshes the page, so now I just need to clear cache on each refresh and stop when a page change is detected (overall function is like a page monitor but clears cache after each refresh).

---or----

```
javascript:
timeout=prompt("Set timeout [s]");
current=location.href;
if(timeout>0)
  setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout);
else
  location.replace(current);
function reload(){
  setTimeout('reload()',1000*timeout);
  fr4me='<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame src=\''+current+'\'/>';
  fr4me+='</frameset>';
  with(document){write(fr4me);void(close())};
}
```

Edit 3: found [this](http://ostermiller.org/bookmarklets/clearcookies.js) for clearing cookies (which should be sufficient):

Edit 4: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369726/javascript-code-to-detect-any-page-changes-maybe-via-ajax) checks for page changes:

Now how do I put this together?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: can you show us what you have tried to do ?

Comment: What is your main objective? Can you show your code?

Comment: Running on the same domain, it shouldn't be a big deal with either JS Interval or `meta` refresh, but crossdomain probably won't be possible with default browsers.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/179514/7581087 and just put this on the new tab `<script>function deleteAllCookies(){/*CODE FROM LINK*/};setInterval("deleteAllCookies();",60000);</script>` - this should delete all cookies from "localhost" domain every minute